# Android - imageview from one image to another image

Tags: android

How to change the image when the `button` is clicked, and when the same button is clicked again return the previous image?

Comment: What have you tried so f...I mean, what's the issue you're having in your code?

Comment: Simply use a if statement in the onClickListener to switch from an image to an other using setImageDrawable on your ImageView

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming you have your two images in the **drawable** folder. Replace all the `ids` with the proper ones and copy this code:

```
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    i = 0;
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId)
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            handleClick();
    });
}
```

And make a private method that's called `handleClick()`:

```
private void handleClick(){
    if( i++ % 2 == 0){
        myImageView.setBackground(R.drawable.first);
        return;
    }
    myImageView.setBackground(R.drawable.second);
}
```